# How to make uranium pellets produce heat?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Assume I have a uranium pellet as follows. What should I do to make it produce heat? And what is the physical condition of this pellet from which I know it must be replaced with the new one? Most books do not explain what I want to know.

[image]

Comment: It will produce a small amount of heat by existing? As it decays, energy is released.

Comment: @toonarmycaptain: How can I produce more heat, for example to boil a cup of coffee?

Comment: Re, "How do I know I have to replace the pellet...?" Go to school, and get a degree in nuclear engineering.  Seriously.  Each time an atom of Uranium undergoes fission, you get two or more atoms of something else, and most of those will be highly radioactive, and soon will decay into yet other elements. The pure uranium that you started with soon will become a mixture of dozens of different radioactive elements,... A mixture that changes over time, and one in which there are many different chemical and nuclear interactions between them that you will need to understand.

Comment: ...either that or, wait for your reactor to blow up, and then use your time machine to send an e-mail back to your past self saying, "time to replace the fuel." The root cause of the Chernobyl disaster was inexperienced operators attempting an unfamiliar procedure, with safety systems turned off, and a reactor that was due for re-fueling. Controlling the reaction rate of old fuel is much more difficult than controlling the reaction rate of fresh fuel.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity well essentially you straddle the line between natural-state uranium and enriched-packaged-to-explode uranium. Pack more/purer uranium in a mass not large enough to undergo an explosive chain reaction, but enough to produce enough radiation to boil some water? NB This also produces all manner of radiation/decay particles that would make said coffee unsafe to drink...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say whether you're talking about natural uranium or enriched uranium. Either way, the half-lives are too long for an [RTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator); the decay rate is inversely proportional to the half-life. Therefore you would have to build a reactor. It's possible to build a reactor with natural uranium, but you would need many tons of uranium and moderator. This was how the first reactor was constructed: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Pile-1 . Your reactor could be smaller if you could obtain enriched uranium, but I don't think anyone is going to sell it to you.

Comment: Could you elaborate more what I have to do with the pallet in the reactor? The term reactor is too abstract.  Do I have to accelerate a neutron and bump it into the pellet?  What happens on the pellet, does it get something like burnt? How do  I know I have to replace the pellet with the new ones?

Comment: Building a fission reactor that uses natural uranium fuel is not merely "possible." 
 It's practical as well:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANDU_reactor